# JavaScript - Get data of first cell of selected table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="newtable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Room No</th>
                        <th>AC</th>
                        <th>Deluxe</th>
                        <th>Tariff</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach var="room" items="${myrooms}">
                        <tr bgcolor="#4B476F" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#4B476F';">

                            <td class="nr"><c:out value="${room.roomno}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${room.ac}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${room.deluxe}" /></td>
                            <td>&#8377;<c:out value="${room.price}" /></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="mybutton" onclick="rowFunction()">Pay</button> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
```

On clicking the button corresponding to every row, I want my script to return the Room number i.e. the first cell data of the row. I have tried a lot of things after referring various articles on the Internet. Nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IJtkH)

```
$(window).on('click', '.mybutton' ,function() {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.nr').text());
    //Or you can use, which is even better
    //alert($(this).parent().siblings('.nr').text());
});
```

Here, the selector is pretty simple, we are first binding `click` event on the button, and `onclick` we select the `button` element parent i.e `td` and we select the parent of `td` i.e `tr` and later we find an element with a `class` of `.nr`

You can also write `td.nr` instead of just `.nr` to be more specific.

Your rows are being dynamically added, in order for your click listener to work you will have to [delegate the events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation/1688293#1688293)

Credits to [@Patsy Issa](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18176344#18176344) for suggesting `.siblings()`

Comment: I am getting a blank alert() dialog box on Chrome. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mybutton").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

usually im using DataTables js for solution, you can check at: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()